# Is there a Java library for parsing printf format strings?

Tags: java, printf

I'm writing an emulator for a machine with a 'printf' opcode, and while I'm aware of the Formatter class which will probably be good enough for actually formatting the strings, I need a way to count the number of arguments which are consumed by the printf call.

Off the top of my head, I could probably do something with a regex to count the number of '%'s, but I'm not too familiar with format strings, so I might not count properly... (excluding escaped ones, etc)

edit: I actually need the number of parameter, along with a mapping of parameter # to parameter type, so, for example, "hello %s %+.3i" would give {0 -> String, 1 -> Integer}

Comment: are you looking for something that parses format strings valid for the Formatter class, or format strings valid for the C printf? (e.g. supports `%*s` or `%*.*f` strings which take 2 or 3 arguments, so you can't just count the number of %s)

Comment: the only types of arguments which apply in my case are characters, 32-bit signed integers, 64-bit doubles, and null-terminated strings. Otherwise it should act like c printf, so I guess Formatter isn't exactly right, but it will probably work for my purposes, as the input is coming from a compiler I wrote anyway.

Comment: Hmm. If you wrote a compiler, can't you write a (relatively) simple grammar parser for whatever variant of `printf()` you want to support, and use the abstract syntax tree to generate the argument count? more work than a simple library call, but if you have tools like ANTLR or whatever to do the parsing, I would think it wouldn't be that hard, and you could make sure your program works correctly. The only reason I bring this up is that a full printf parsing isn't so easy. If you can live without the variable-width syntax, that simplifies it quite a bit, and you could probably do it with Regex

Comment: the behaviour of the printf opcode is a bit... underspecified. "Does a C-style printf, Does not support 'I64' (wide integer) or 'n' or 'p' (pointer) specifiers". I'm doing this 'for fun' in the context of a compilers class, and I don't really feel like dealing with the complexities of format strings myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use a Regex that is something like `%(?:%|[0-9]+([dox]))` and examine the format type specifier that way?

There was another SO topic about [parsing sprintf format strings with regex's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446285/validate-sprintf-format-from-input-field-with-regex) which might give you some more ideas. Unless you specify what features of printf() you want, it's sort of hard to recommend an exact regex.

Or, as I mentioned in my comment, if you're using another compiler tool anyway like ANTLR or Parboiled, use that to deconstruct the format string into appropriate pieces via a simple grammar specification.

Answer (score 7):

[Format Strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) interpret every `%` as a placeholder, with literal `%` being escaped as `%%`, so it should be as simple as this:

```
String formatString;
int parameterCount = formatString.replace("%%", "").split("%").length - 1;
```

This code first removes all escaped (doubled) `%`, then counts `%` via split.

Comment: actually, now that I think about it, I actually need a mapping of parameter # -> parameter type, ugh.